# Masonry/Isotope - filter visible in the URL

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-isotope, masonry

I've approached an weird issue. My theme's isotope code is following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //ISOTOPE MAIN
    var  $container = $('#isotope-container');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.isotope({
         itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
         filter: '.home',
         resizesContainer: true
    });

    //ISOTOPE FILTER
    $(function(){
        var $container = $('#isotope-container');
            optionFilter = jQuery('#filter'),
            optionFilterLinks = optionFilter.find('a');

        optionFilterLinks.attr('href', '#');

        optionFilterLinks.click(function(){
            var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
           $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.isotope({
                filter : '.' + selector,
                itemSelector : '.isotope-item',
                resizesContainer: true,
            });
                });
            // Highlight the correct filter
            optionFilterLinks.removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });
    });

    //ISOTOPE INFINITE SCROLLING
    $(function(){
      $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : '#page_nav',
            nextSelector : '#page_nav a',
            itemSelector : '.isotope-item',
            loading: {
                loadingText: 'Loading',
                finishedMsg: 'Done Loading',
                img: ''
              }
            },

            function( newElements ) {
              var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
              $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                $('.format-video').fitVids('appended', $newElems);  
              });

              //CALL FUNCTIONS IN Bean_Isotope.callAfterNewElements
              for(var i = 0; i < Bean_Isotope.callAfterNewElements.length; i++) {
                Bean_Isotope.callAfterNewElements[i].call();
              }
            }
          );
      });


    });

});
```

I wanted to incorporate there following solution:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#url-hash

but when I simply copy and paste the jquery - it doesn't work. in my URL appear no filter.

Additionaly ive got a short description of my problem. On my homepage (index.php) im showing items via isotope. In other pages like bio/contact/places i want also DISPLAY a filter menu (i can do that) which points to the index.php + i want to add that filters. So e.g.

if somebody will be on bio page, will click on filter menu ".home" he should be directed to my homepage (index.php) and apply filters..